# Get elements of an array based on indexes from another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays.
One with my data:

```
var tab1 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"];
```

And an other with int:

```
var tab2 = [1,4,5,8,12,15,18];
```

I would like to put in  `tab3` values from `tab1` which have indexes from the values of `tab2`.
I had tried with some `indexOf` // `findIndexe`
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: So you want tab3 = ["two","five","six","nine","thirteen","sixteen","nineteen"] ?

Comment: You can use map to create the array you want. `tab3 = tab2.map(index => tab1[index])`

Comment: *"I had tried"* it's not good enough to just say you tried, really, you should show what you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map your `tab2` array into a new array called `tab3`

```js
const tab1 = [
    "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven",
    "eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen",
    "fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"
];

const tab2 = [1,4,5,8,12,15,18];

const tab3 = tab2.map(index => tab1[index])
console.log(tab3)
```

The question asks for indexes. But if the answer required is the actual string representation of the number, you would search for an `index-1` item in your list.

```js
const tab1 = [
    "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven",
    "eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen",
    "fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"
];

const tab2 = [1,4,5,8,12,15,18];

const tab3 = tab2.map(index => tab1[index -1])
console.log(tab3)
```

Comment: But your answer doesn't produce the results?

Comment: @SamuelG the OP asks for `indexes from the values of tab2` not actual number itself

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()`:

```js
const tab1 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"];

const tab2 = [1,4,5,8,12,15,18];

const tab3 = tab2.map(num => tab1[num - 1]);

console.log(tab3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's iterate the array which contains indexes and put the values of data corresponded index.

```
tab2.forEach(i => { 
    tab3.push(tab1[i]) 
})
```

Comment: Did you actually test before posting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using objects, because there are no indexed arrays in js.

```
var tab1 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","twenty"];

var tab2 = [1,4,5,8,12,15,18];
var tab3 = {};
tab2.forEach((val) => {
    tab3[val] = tab1[val];
})

console.log(tab3);
```

Of course key and values of tab3 will not match because js arrays are zero based.